# Get owner's access permissions using C++ and stat

Tags: c++, linux, file, mode, stat

How can I get the file owner's access permissions using stat from sys/stat.h using C++ in Kubuntu Linux?

Currently, I get the type of file like this:

```
  struct stat results;  

  stat(filename, &results);

  cout << "File type: ";
  if (S_ISDIR(results.st_mode))
    cout << "Directory";
  else if (S_ISREG(results.st_mode))
    cout << "File";
  else if (S_ISLNK(results.st_mode))
    cout << "Symbolic link";
  else cout << "File type not recognised";
  cout << endl;
```

I know I should use t_mode's file mode bits, but I don't know how. [See sys/stat.h](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sysstat.h.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  struct stat results;  

  stat(filename, &results);

  cout << "Permissions: ";
  if (results.st_mode & S_IRUSR)
    cout << "Read permission ";
  if (results.st_mode & S_IWUSR)
    cout << "Write permission ";
  if (results.st_mode & S_IXUSR)
    cout << "Exec permission";
  cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The owner permission bits are given by the macro `S_IRWXU` from `<sys/stat.h>`.  The value will be multiplied by 64 (0100 octal), hence:

```
cout << "Owner mode: " << ((results.st_mode & S_IRWXU) >> 6) << endl;
```

This will print out a value between 0 and 7.  There are similar masks for group (`S_IRWXG`) and others (`S_IRWXO`), with shifts of 3 and 0 respectively.  There are also separate masks for each of the 12 individual permission bits.